# How to spread an object into a classes properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, spread-syntax

Basically here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

```js
class Person {
  constructor (obj) {
    this.first = ''
    this.last = ''
    this.age = ''

    if (obj) {
      Object.assign(this, ...obj)
    }
  }
}

const a = new Person()
console.log('Not spreading: ', a)

const b = new Person({ first: 'Alex', last: 'Cory', age: 27 })
console.log('Spreading: ', b)
```

Is there a way to spread an object like this to populate a class?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), you don't use spread notation; just remove the `...` (and optionally remove the `if`):

```js
class Person {
    constructor (obj) {
        this.first = "";
        this.last = "";
        this.age = ""; // Consider a number rather than ""?

        // (No need for the `if`)
        Object.assign(this, obj);    // <============ No ...
    }
}

const a = new Person();
console.log("Not spreading: ", a);

const b = new Person({ first: "Alex", last: "Cory", age: 27 });
console.log("Spreading: ", b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that you don't need the `if`, because `Object.assign` ignores `null` or `undefined` sources.

> Is there a way to spread an object like this to populate a class?

Not in this example, where you're doing it in the constructor and so the object already exists. There is [property spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), but it's in object initializers (object literals), so doesn't apply to putting objects in an *existing* object. That's what `Object.assign` is for.

Comment: We also don't need the `if (obj) { … }`, because Object.assign handles null and undefined. [MDN quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#sect1): "Note: Object.assign() does not throw on null or undefined sources."

Comment: @ANeves - Indeed! :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could use deconstruction and take only the properties, you need.

```js
class Person {
    constructor ({ first = '', last = '', age = '' } = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, { first, last, age });
    }
}

const a = new Person()
console.log('Not spreading: ', a)

const b = new Person({ first: 'Alex', last: 'Cory', age: 27, foo: 42 })
console.log('Spreading: ', b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
class Person {
  constructor (obj) {
    this.firstName = ''
    this.lastName = ''
    this.age = ''
    if (obj) {
      Object.assign(this, obj)
    }
  }
}

const a = new Person()
console.log('Not spreading: ', a)

const b = new Person({ firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Cory', age: 27 })
console.log('Spreading: ', b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer to use a seperate method as it is not possible to have multiple constructors in JS. In the following example I create new objects using a `static fromObject()` method which returns a new object. Therefore you can keep your normal constructor and create new objects using spread syntax as well.

Note: I am using typescript here.

```js
export class Point {
    readonly x: number
    readonly y: number

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    static fromObject({x, y}: {x: number, y: number}) {
        return new Point(x, y)
    }
}
```